# How to minify js file with ajax call in Sublime 3 using Minify plugin?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, sublimetext3, minify

I installed [Minify Plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Minify) for Sublime 3. All components of Node.js were installed without errors. In my js file I use ajax call with this heading:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        action: 'hihealthy_bmi_test_processing',
        formData,
        post_id,
    },
})
```

When I try to minify this file this error occurs:

[image: screenshot of the error]

This same error occurs when I try to minify this file online.

So my question is how can I minify this file properly? What's causing the error? I am pretty sure in syntax cause this file works properly. I suspect it's because some JSON format is involved, but I don't know Node.js to figure out how to minify this.

Comment: just use vscode man

Comment: I like sublime and I got used to it... Have all my plugins and packages... But thank you for suggestion. And I'm not a man :)

Comment: haha, okay just try vscode once, you will love it.. believe me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error can only mean that you are using node<5 i guess which doesn't support es6 where you can use the shorthand formData instead of formData: formData. So upgrade your node or use another minifier that supports this syntax.

Also if you are going to publish this code you may want to use babel since es6 is not support in older browsers. Checkout kangax browser support for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I replaced formData: formData and it worked like magic. Didn't know that my was shorted version. Thank you very much :)